# Update qCombobox inside qtableWidget with sqlite data

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt

I have a problem with my current code, I have inserted in qTableWidget a combobox with with setCellWidget method, but I need to update the value in that qComboBox as I do with

```
ui->tW_Datos->setItem(fila, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(consultar.value(2).toByteArray().constData()))
```

for example.

How Can I update my combobox with the value from SQLite?

```
void Complejidad::MostrarDatos()
{
QString consulta;
consulta.append("SELECT * FROM componentes WHERE Componente='" + buscar + "'");
QSqlQuery consultar;
consultar.prepare(consulta);

if(consultar.exec()){
    qDebug() << "Se ha consultado correctamente";
}else{
    qDebug() << "No se ha consultado correctamente" << consultar.lastError();
}

int fila=0;

ui->tW_Datos->setRowCount(0);

while(consultar.next()){
    QComboBox *combo;
    combo = new QComboBox;
    combo->addItems({"", "Simple", "Media", "Alta"});
    combo->setProperty("row", 1 - ui->tW_Datos->rowCount());
    combo->setProperty("column", 1);

    ui->tW_Datos->insertRow(fila);
    ui->tW_Datos->setItem(fila, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(consultar.value(2).toByteArray().constData()));
    connect(combo, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(const QString&)), this, SLOT(OnComboIndexChanged(const QString&)));
    ui->tW_Datos->setCellWidget (fila, 1, combo);

}

}
```

Combobox:

[image: 1]

How can I update those combobox with the data from my DB (SQlite)??

Comment: Hello, I don't know exactly what are you trying to do, but if you want to set the selected option of the `QCombobox` you could simply call `combo->setSelectedIndex()` with the index of the option you want before adding it to the table widget.

Comment: Well I´m trayng to update a setCellWidget () with a combobox object inside a qtablewidget, I need to update the index of my combobox with the current sqlite data